# how to show multiple wheel or Components in Picker of React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have use this reference url https://snack.expo.io/HkjxvRS-W for adding Picker in React Native, but here it's show only one wheel in Picker, but I want to display two wheel in Picker, so how do I do it ? is anyone have any idea?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Picker } from 'react-native';

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValue: ''
            arrayPickers: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten']
        }
    }

    render() {
       return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <Picker
            style={{width: 320}}
            selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
            onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({selectedValue: value})}>
            {this.state.arrayPickers.map((value, index) => (
                <Picker.Item label={value} value={value} key={index}           />
             ))}
          </Picker>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

From Above code I am able to show one Wheel or Component in Picker, but I want to show two Wheel or Component in Picker.

Please have look below image for further understanding.

[Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbVQQ.png)

Comment: Your question is off-topic! please take a look at [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. check [ask]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code?

Comment: didn't the lib did the trick for you?

Comment: @bruno I have added sample code please have look.

Comment: The picker from react native documentation doesn't let you do what you want, take a look at the lib I post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library that you can use to achieve what you want [react-native-picker](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker), as didn't specify how you wanted or posted any source code, I feel like this could help you.

Comment: I have tried above library with another purpose, but while implement time it's give some errors And raised the issue in GitHub, but it looks it's not supporting any more in react native.